# How to insert data with PostgreSQL query into this table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, sql-insert

I need help regarding exact query to successfully insert data into below created table, without violating constraint and fulfill the criteria that the table needed. I tried using below query, but fail

```
INSERT INTO public.study_subject(
        study_subject_id, label, secondary_label, subject_id, study_id, 
        status_id, enrollment_date, date_created, date_updated, owner_id, 
        update_id, oc_oid, time_zone, user_id, user_status_id)
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 
        ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 
        ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);
```

below is the query to create said table

```
  CREATE TABLE public.study_subject
(
  study_subject_id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('study_subject_study_subject_id_seq'::regclass),
  label character varying(30),
  secondary_label character varying(30),
  subject_id integer,
  study_id integer,
  status_id integer,
  enrollment_date date,
  date_created timestamp with time zone,
  date_updated timestamp with time zone,
  owner_id integer,
  update_id integer,
  oc_oid character varying(40) NOT NULL,
  time_zone character varying(255) DEFAULT ''::character varying,
  user_id integer,
  user_status_id integer,
  CONSTRAINT pk_study_subject PRIMARY KEY (study_subject_id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_project__reference_study2 FOREIGN KEY (study_id)
      REFERENCES public.study (study_id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fk_study_reference_subject FOREIGN KEY (subject_id)
      REFERENCES public.subject (subject_id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE SET NULL,
  CONSTRAINT fk_study_su_fk_study__status FOREIGN KEY (status_id)
      REFERENCES public.status (status_id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT fk_study_su_fk_study__user_acc FOREIGN KEY (owner_id)
      REFERENCES public.user_account (user_id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT study_subject_user_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
      REFERENCES public.user_account (user_id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT uniq_study_subject_oid UNIQUE (oc_oid)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

please help , any link/sources that will help in this matter will be greatly appreciated, thank you :)

Comment: What does "Fail" mean here? Did you get an error? Can you share that? This table is filled with Foreign Key relationships, which means that the values you insert into those columns that are tagged as a "FOREIGN KEY" must exist already in the tables that are mentioned in the FOREIGN KEY constraint definition. For instance the `study_id` you insert into this table must already exist in column `study_id` in your `public.study` table BEFORE attempting to insert that `study_id` here.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql?

Comment: @JNevill yes sir , i tried to insert data into the table via express.js , the error is "invalid input syntax for integer: "SS_3"" which is clearly that i insert char into char column , and i have already filled for insert values study_id with existing study_id

Comment: @jarlh postgresql sir , i think those two have same query don't they?

Comment: note that i already tried using sequelize , and have been converted the existing tables to sequelize model, but please tell me which is better using query or ORM sequelize for building the app using express.js?

Comment: MySQL and Postgresql, and most other dbms products are similar in many ways, but different in others.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the **exact** error message you get.